# SQL Combine 2 Different Rows into 1

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have a table like this, called Inventory:

```
**Fruit**        **Price**
orange            4
grapefruit        10
banana            15
```

I would like to write a select statement that would show the output like this:

```
**Fruit**   **Price**
citrus      14
banana      15
```

Still new to SQL so I can't figure out the SELECT statement for this. If this is the SELECT statement that would give me the first set of results above (itemized fruit), how can I change it so that it combines oranges and grapefruits and display the result as citrus?

```
SELECT
INV.fruit,
INV.price
FROM
INVENTORY      INV
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression to translate oranges and grapefruits to citrus:

```
SELECT   CASE WHEN fruit IN ('orange', 'grapefruit')
              THEN 'citrus' 
              ELSE fruit 
         END,
         SUM(price)
FROM     inventory
GROUP BY CASE WHEN fruit IN ('orange', 'grapefruit')
              THEN 'citrus' 
              ELSE fruit 
         END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` statement:

```
select (case when fruit in ('orange', 'grapefruit') then citrus else fruit end) as fruit,
       sum(price) as price
from inventory i
group by (case when fruit in ('orange', 'grapefruit') then citrus else fruit end);
```

Answer (score 1):

If `citrus` is a case which you need to use multiple times, then use `WITH` clause, also called `subquery factoring`.

`WITH data AS(`
   `SELECT  (case when fruit in ('orange', 'grapefruit') then citrus else fruit end)) as fruit,
       sum(price) as price
from inventory i
group by (case when fruit in ('orange', 'grapefruit') then citrus else fruit end)
)......`

For more such cases, just include the subqueries in the WITH clause. Finally, select whatever you want from it.

For example, 
`WITH citrus as...., bitter as...etc.`